# Extract string between two symbols

Tags: unix, sed

I am looking for a way to extract the string between "/" and "_" in the following examples. I tried this command but it doesn't work with special characters: `sed -e 's//(.*\)_/\1/'`

```
input:

Sometext/CPCT02010547T_sometext
```

out:

```
CPCT02010547T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -n 's/.*\/\(.*\)_.*/\1/p'
sed -En 's~.*/([^_]*)_.*~\1~p'
```

The `-n` option suppresses the default line output and `p` prints the result of substitution.

The first pattern is a POSIX BRE regex:

- `.*` - match any text
- `\/` - matches a `/`
- `\(.*\)` - a capturing group (`\1`) in a POSIX BRE (first) pattern
- `_` - a `_` char
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The second regex is a POSIX ERE regex (note the `-E` option) and the `~` is used as a regex delimiter char to avoid escaping `/`. The only big difference between the first and second is the capturing group pattern, `([^_]*)` matches any zero or more chars other than a `_`.